# Encoding a CALL instruction to call a function

Tags: c, instruction-set, x86

I am trying to create an assembler which is able to encode instructions at runtime (for a JIT compiler). Sorry for the long code snippet, but this is the shortest compilable example which shows my problem.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <windows.h>

typedef void (*function)();
uint8_t* instructionBuffer;
uint32_t pos;

/**
 * Creates the instruction buffer;
 */
void assembler_initialize() {
    instructionBuffer = (uint8_t*) VirtualAllocEx(GetCurrentProcess(), 0, 1024,
    MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    pos = 0;
}

/**
 * Writes a call to the given address to the instruction buffer
 */
void assembler_emit_call(uint32_t value) {
    // CALL opcode
    instructionBuffer[pos++] = 0xFF;

    // opcode extension 2, read a 32bit address
    instructionBuffer[pos++] = 0x15;

    // Address as little endian
    instructionBuffer[pos++] = (value >> 0) & 0xFF;
    instructionBuffer[pos++] = (value >> 8) & 0xFF;
    instructionBuffer[pos++] = (value >> 16) & 0xFF;
    instructionBuffer[pos++] = (value >> 24) & 0xFF;
}

/**
 * Writes a RET to the instruction buffer
 */
void assembler_emit_ret() {
    instructionBuffer[pos++] = 0xC3;
}

/**
 * The function to call
 */
void __cdecl myFunction() {
    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
}

/**
 *
 */
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    assembler_initialize();
    assembler_emit_call((uint32_t) &myFunction);
    assembler_emit_ret();

    // Output the address
    std::cout << std::hex << (uint32_t) &myFunction << std::endl;

    // Output the opcodes
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        std::cout << std::hex << (uint32_t) instructionBuffer[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // Call the function
    function f = (function) instructionBuffer;
    f();

    return 0;
}
```

The output tells me, that the address of `myFunction` is `0x4017c5`, and that these opcodes were written:

```
CALL   ModRM   Addr (le)     RET    Zeros
ff     15      c5 17 40 0    c3     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

Still, my program crashes when trying to execute the code. Did I miss something when encoding the `CALL` instruction?

Comment: What if the call itself works but the *called* routine crashes? Did you check that?

Comment: Hmm, when simply calling the routine `myFunction` the `Hello world!` text is printed out.

Comment: Can you step the JITed code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't work because the call instruction is incorrect. Actually there is no `CALL absolute_address` instruction on the x86.

In your example you generate following X86 code:

```
FF 15 xx xx xx xx
```

which is an indirect call to the adress xx xx xx xx. This will take the address found at xx xx xx xx and do the call there.

**Example**

```
FF 15 10 20 30 00
```

This will look at the adress 0x302010 :

```
00302010: 11 22 33 00 xx xx xx xx
```

where it finds the value 0x00332211 and the calls the function at that address.

With the following modifications in `assembler_emit_call` the program works fine.

```
void assembler_emit_call(uint32_t value) {
    // CALL opcode
    instructionBuffer[pos++] = 0xb8;  // mov  eax, address

    // Address as little endian
    instructionBuffer[pos++] = (value >> 0) & 0xFF;
    instructionBuffer[pos++] = (value >> 8) & 0xFF;
    instructionBuffer[pos++] = (value >> 16) & 0xFF;
    instructionBuffer[pos++] = (value >> 24) & 0xFF;

    instructionBuffer[pos++] = 0xff ;  // call eax
    instructionBuffer[pos++] = 0xd0 ;
    instructionBuffer[pos++] = 0xc3 ;  // ret
}
```

BTW

```
    instructionBuffer[pos++] = (value >> 0) & 0xFF;
    instructionBuffer[pos++] = (value >> 8) & 0xFF;
    instructionBuffer[pos++] = (value >> 16) & 0xFF;
    instructionBuffer[pos++] = (value >> 24) & 0xFF;
```

can be replaced by

```
    *(DWORD*)(instructionBuffer + pos) = value ;
    pos += 4 ;
```